# With relation to Random Forests, what is the difference between OOB and Logloss error?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

Are they both cost functions? As in, would you look at both when evaluating error or are they really separate measures? Confused about the logloss error and am having difficulty finding information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you've trained some classifier on some train data, *x<sub>tr</sub>, y<sub>tr</sub>*, and you've obtained some fit classifier *m*. Now for some *x, y*, you take the classifier's results *ŷ  = ŷ<sub>m</sub>(x)*.

- [log loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification) is a function that takes *y* and *ŷ*, and outputs how well the classifier did on the data.
- [*OOB* (out of bag)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-bag_error) simply means that you do *not* take *x<sub>tr</sub>, y<sub>tr</sub>*, the dataset you used for training, as *x, y*, the dataset you use for evaluating the performance. Rather it means that *x, y* is *x<sub>te</sub>, y<sub>te</sub>*, some dataset you left out of training (probably specifically for this purpose).

The two concepts are orthogonal, therefore:

- With a fit classifier and an OOB dataset, you can use log loss or not.
- You can measure the log loss on an OOB dataset, or on the original train dataset (in the latter case, though, you should be very careful how you interpret the results - it's an awful estimator of how well the predictor actually works).

Comment: Technically _any_ loss function is a function that outputs how well the classifier did. :) Log loss is negative log-likeliness function on probability of predictions - just a note for OP.